# remove a item in a recyclerview with swipe in mvvmcross

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I create a MvxRecyclerview with swipe, i need remove the swiped item of the recyclerview, but when i make the swipe, remove the item and after appear another item in bottom of recyclerview.

**Nombre.cs**

```
public class Nombre
{
    public string _name;
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewModel.cs**

```
public class RecyclerViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    //private IList<Nombre> Items;
    NombreGenesisService lista;

    public RecyclerViewModel()
    {
        //Nombres lista = new Nombres();
        lista = new NombreGenesisService();

        Items = new List<Nombre>
        {
            new Nombre()
            {
                _name = "sebastian",
            },

             new Nombre()
            {
                _name = "Natalia",
            },

            new Nombre()
            {
                _name = "Angelica",
            },
            new Nombre()
            {
                _name = "Octavio",
            },
        };
    }

    private List<Nombre> _items;

    public List<Nombre> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items);
        }
    }
}
```

}

**RecyclerViewFragment.cs**

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment : BaseFragment<RecyclerViewModel>
{
    protected override int FragmentId
    {
        get
        {
            return Resource.Layout.fragment_example_recyclerview;
        }
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var recyclerView = ignore.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.my_recycler_view);

        if (recyclerView != null)
        {
            recyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
            var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity);
            recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(recyclerView.GetAdapter());
            ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
            itemTouchHelper.AttachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
            recyclerView.SetItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        }

        return ignore;
    }

    public override void OnDestroyView()
    {
        base.OnDestroyView();

    }
}
```

**SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback.cs**

```
class SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback : ItemTouchHelper.Callback
{
    // private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private readonly RecyclerView.Adapter _adapter;
    RecyclerViewModel lista;
    NombreGenesisService lista2;
    public SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(RecyclerView.Adapter adapter)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
        lista = new RecyclerViewModel();
    }

    public override int GetMovementFlags(RecyclerView p0, RecyclerView.ViewHolder p1)
    {
        int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.Up | ItemTouchHelper.Down;
        int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.Start | ItemTouchHelper.End;
        return MakeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }

    public override bool OnMove(RecyclerView p0, RecyclerView.ViewHolder p1, RecyclerView.ViewHolder p2)
    {
        _adapter.NotifyItemMoved(p1.AdapterPosition, p2.AdapterPosition);
        return true;
    }

    public override void OnSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder p0, int p1)
    {
        lista.Items.RemoveAt(p0.AdapterPosition);
        _adapter.NotifyItemRemoved(p0.AdapterPosition);
    }

}
```

**fragment_example_recyclerview.axml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<MvxRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items;"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_name" />
```

Comment: I've done something like this before. Take a look at my sample here: https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinItemTouchHelper

Comment: didnt help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are creating a ViewModel for your Fragment and a new ViewModel for your RecyclerView in its constructor if iam not wrong. And then you are just removing the Items for the ViewModel in your RecyclerView.

Maybe try to pass your ViewModel from the Fragment to your RecyclerView, though it doesnt seem like a sweet approach it might work. I might try to find a better solution for myself later.

Comment: Need to look at your code then (maybe create a sample project on github) or first check this page here which should be up to date: http://smstuebe.de/2016/05/22/mvvmcross-swipe2dismiss/

Comment: https://github.com/sopoco/Recycle_con_swipe_binding this is the github of the code

Comment: Look at the tutorial i posted before, you need to pass the ViewModel, so you can remove the items in your Observable Collection. At the moment you are always creating a new ViewModel and then Deleting the item in the OnSwipe.